# How it comes that integral of odd function is not even?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I know a rule that integral of an odd function on the complex plane should be an even function. For instance,

$$\int \sin z\, dz=-\cos z +C$$
$$\int z\, dz=\frac {z^2}2 +C$$

etc.

Yet, integral of the function $\frac 1z$ is not even!

$$\int \frac 1z dz=\ln z + C$$

which is neither even nor odd! Its real part is even, but its complex part is not.

How this can be the case? What exactly the exceptions from the rule?

Note that I am interested in complex functions, so do not suggest $\ln |z|$ as the integral, because its derivative on the complex plane is not $1/z$.

Comment: It helps if the function is continuous or at least integrable over an interval $[-a,a]$.

Comment: $1/z\upharpoonright_{(0,\infty)}$ isn't odd.

Comment: @user2345215 $1/z$ is an odd function, following the definition of odd functions. Function cannot be odd on an interval.

Comment: @user2345215 not necessary.

Comment: @Anixx Why don't you find the error by filling the details? What does $\int1/z\,dz=\ln z+C$ actually mean? Can you translate it into something more specific to find the error? This question seems lazy to me, that's why I gave -1.